# Calculate/Determine Hours for Nightshift in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, logic

Here is the table for the employee's logs:

[image: employee's logs]

And what I want is to generate the time ins and time out of employees. like this:

[image: time in time out]

Can anyone help me for this? Any added logic or algorithm will be accepted.

Comment: There will always be even number of records for an employee and minimum time will be `in` and subsequent will be `out` and so on, Is that correct? Also give the data in tabular format rather than image so someone can copy it if they want.

Comment: Well...let's see what you've tried.

Comment: If i'll used the MIN TimeIn and MAXTimeOut per employe, It will just be based or grouped per DATE. What I need is for nightshift hours, from this day to another day.

Comment: I'm already done on computing hours for Dayshift, the problem is the condition if an employee is on nightshift.

Answer (score -1):

This is one way. And it will work for day/night any shifts, provided, the first `min(datetime)` represent `IN`.

[Rextester Sample](http://rextester.com/KKSS9311)

```
select  t.enno
        ,max(datetime) as time_out
        ,min(datetime) as time_in
        ,time_to_sec(timediff(max(datetime), min(datetime) )) / 3600 
            as No_of_hours
from 
(
    SELECT
    floor(@row1 := @row1 + 0.5) as day,
    t.*
    FROM Table4356 t,
     (SELECT @row1 := 0.5) r1
    order by t.datetime
) t
group by t.day,t.enno
;
```

Output

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| enno |      time_out       |       time_in       | No_of_hours |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|    6 | 16.05.2017 06:30:50 | 15.05.2017 18:30:50 |     12,0000 |
|    6 | 17.05.2017 05:30:50 | 16.05.2017 18:10:50 |     11,3333 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Explanation:

```
    SELECT
    floor(@row1 := @row1 + 0.5) as day,
    t.*
    FROM Table4356 t,
     (SELECT @row1 := 0.5) r1
    order by t.datetime
```

This query uses sequence to increment `@row1` with `0.5`, so you will get `1 1.5 2 2.5`. Now if you just get the integer part of with with `floor`, you will generate sequece like `1 1 2 2`. So this query will give you this output

```
+-----+------+---------------------+
| day | enno |      datetime       |
+-----+------+---------------------+
|   1 |    6 | 15.05.2017 18:30:50 |
|   1 |    6 | 16.05.2017 06:30:50 |
|   2 |    6 | 16.05.2017 18:10:50 |
|   2 |    6 | 17.05.2017 05:30:50 |
+-----+------+---------------------+
```

Now you can group by `day` and get `max` and `min` time.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try on this one. Will give you an update if I got questions. Thanks dude :)

Comment: Hi Utsav. the problem is if an employee got multiple ins it will give an output like this :

 1 |    6 | 15.05.2017 18:30:50
 1 |    6 | 15.05.2017 19:30:50
 2 |    6 | 16.05.2017 06:30:50

It counts the other input as next day :(

Comment: That's not in the screenshot you gave. And I asked the same in comments too but you didn't reply there. This solution is for the sample you gave. If you have different scenario, ask a different question. Accept the answer worked for your give sample so this question can ve closed.

Comment: My own view is that answering questions as poor as this one does a disservice to the community

Comment: Well thats your opinion. I am here to learn new things and I love to solve these kind of scenarios. I would continue to answer them best I can. Cheers!

Comment: Can you guys help me with this one please? :3

Comment: @Enrico - Try to come up it by yourself with the help of query I gave. If not able to, ask a different question with complete sample data in tabular format.

Comment: I already did. But I just can't come up with different solution :3

Comment: Then ask a different question please. Read [How to ask a good SQL Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: Hi Utsav! Here is the newly formatted question. Help me with this one please.
[Calculating hours for nightshift with multiple logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243610/calculating-determine-hours-on-nightshift-with-multiple-logs)