# Calculating/Determine Hours on Nightshift with multiple logs

Tags: java, mysql, time

[This are the logs of employee # 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPFdI.png)

[And here is my expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PURSK.png)

I've tried this query :

```
SELECT a.`id` AS employ_id, 
      ADDTIME(MIN(a.adjustedDateTime), '12:00:00') AS check_in_time,   
      ADDTIME(MAX(a.adjustedDateTime), '12:00:00') AS check_out_time,   
     TIMEDIFF(
        MAX(a.adjustedDateTime),
        MIN(a.adjustedDateTime)   ) AS working_time,   
      COUNT(0) AS report_times,   
   DATE_FORMAT(a.adjustedDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS report_date 
 FROM   (SELECT 
    `EnNo` AS id,
    SUBTIME(
      CONCAT(DATE(DateTime), ' ', TIME(DateTime)), '12:00:00') AS adjustedDateTime   
      FROM
    bio) a  
   GROUP BY a.`id`,   
     DATE_FORMAT(a.adjustedDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d')  
        ORDER BY a.`id`, DATE('DateTime');
```

[And here is the output, not calculating the dayshift hours :

> ---  Empid - | ----------TimeIn---------- |----------TimeOut------- |----------Hours----- |
>
> ```
> 00000006   2017-05-15 18:14:13   2017-05-16 06:30:05   12:15:52.000000
> 00000006   2017-05-16 18:10:18   2017-05-17 05:30:50   11:20:32.000000
> 00000006   2017-05-18 08:30:05   2017-05-18 08:30:05   00:00:00.000000 
> 00000006   2017-05-18 15:30:05   2017-05-18 15:30:05   00:00:00.000000
> ```

Can anyone help me with this? or any suggestion with it's algorithm or anything. Thanks. Sorry if I can't post the images, not enough reputation :(

Comment: what would be "night shift hours" from a business perspective? When does it start, when does it end? can you give table definition for your worklog table?

Comment: My definition of nightshift would be 10pm onwards. I just need help on getting the work hours for dayshift and nightshift. Like what is given above. I need help please :3

Comment: Your calculation above for working time seems off as well. it looks like lines 3 and 4 would be one dayshift from 08:30 to 15:30 ?

Comment: Yes sir. but my query doesn't take it as 1 day because the query is for nightshift. heeelllppppp

Comment: dou you have any indication in your work-log-table which is a "coming" timestamp and which is a "going" timestamp?

Comment: I don't. Only the logs as what is given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have the following:

- a SQL statemeng giving start and end-times for any shift that might've been an nightshift,
- a calculation for the time difference.

Now, what is night-shift?

- all hours on start-day that occur after 10pm
- all hours on end-day that occur before 7am (guessing on my part)

So, instead of simply using "start of work" timestamp, you use the maximum between this start of work and 10pm and the minimum of end-of-work and 7am:

Note that I had to add some conditions to guess which is a probable end-of-work time (before noon) and which is a probable start-of-work-time (after noon) for this nightshift calculation:

```
create table worktime_stackoverflow (id int, DateTime datetime);
delete from worktime_stackoverflow where id > 0;
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (1, '2017-05-15 18:14:13');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (2, '2017-05-16 06:30:05');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (3, '2017-05-17 22:30:45');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (4, '2017-05-18 09:30:05');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (5, '2017-05-20 10:45:15');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (6, '2017-05-20 19:31:25');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (5, '2017-05-21 16:45:15');
insert into worktime_stackoverflow values (6, '2017-05-22 03:17:25');


select DATE(w.DateTime) day_of_report
  # Start of nightshift
, CONCAT(DATE(MIN(w.DateTime)), ' ' , '22:00:00') start_nightshift,
  # actual start of work
       MIN(w.DateTime) start_of_work,
  # mathematical max() of the two
       GREATEST(
          CONCAT(DATE(MIN(w.DateTime)), ' ' , '22:00:00'),
          Min(w.DateTime)
        ) nightshift_work_start,
  # end of nightshift-hours
        CONCAT(ADDDATE(DATE(MIN(w.DateTime)), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ' , '07:00:00') end_nightshift
  # the following worklog entry (= end of work)
        ,(SELECT MIN(w2.DateTime) as following_time FROM worktime_stackoverflow w2 WHERE w2.DateTime > w.DateTime AND TIME(w2.DateTime) < '12:00:00'
                  AND DATEDIFF(w2.DateTime, w.DateTime) < 2) as end_of_work
  # mathematical minimum of these two
      ,LEAST(
           (SELECT MIN(w2.DateTime) as following_time FROM worktime_stackoverflow w2 WHERE w2.DateTime > w.DateTime AND TIME(w2.DateTime) < '12:00:00'
              AND DATEDIFF(w2.DateTime, w.DateTime) < 2),
          CONCAT(ADDDATE(DATE(MIN(w.DateTime)), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ' , '07:00:00')
          ) nightshift_work_end  
from worktime_stackoverflow w
   # make sure to not use end-of-nightshift loutout times
   where TIME(w.DateTime) > '12:00:00'
GROUP by DATE(w.DateTime);
```

For final solution you'd have to add in employee id and so on...

Comment: This will help a lot. What about the dayshift ? Let's say from 9am to 5pm.

Comment: you said you had those... that would simply be those with min and max on the same day and not equal, right?

Comment: Yes i do. But on what part of the query will i insert it? I'll add my query for dayshift to yours.

Like this:

SELECT EnNo,MAX(DateTime), MIN(DateTime) FROM bio GROUP BY DATE(`DateTime`), EmpNo;

Comment: You could UNION both selects once you have the columns aligned

Comment: What I mean is how will I trigger the Dayshift query. The one that you did only selects the inputs from 10pm onwards. Sorry Jan, i'm not good in sql queries.